# How do I change the location of post-specific information?

Tags: posts

On each post page is the following information displayed:

> Written by:  nona
>   Date Posted:  April 24th, 2013
>   Category:  drawing writing reading, General
>   Comments:  3 Comments »

Here is an [example link](http://nonaorbach.com/blog/?p=7595).

So the post info is situated in the top of the post. We would like to move it to the bottom of the post page.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Edit your loop and place `<?php the_content(); ?>` before the author, time, category and comment tags instead of after them.

Place it before the `<ul class="meta">`